# How to save onetomany relation between product and tags

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two models. One is Product and another one is Tag. I want setup OneToMany relation between them. After that I want to save tags just like using these format of json.

```
{
    "productName": "katon gokake 1",
    "product_desc": "ASDASasdasdasDASDA",
    "price": 250030.0,
    "category": {
        "id": 302
    },
    "tags": [
        {"tag_name": "new tag"},
{"tag_name": "new tag"}
    ]
    

}
```

The format can be wrong If I am wrong please give me a correction of it. Here is the models:

```
package com.example.springpractice.Models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String productName;

    private float price;

    private String product_desc;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Tags> tags = new ArrayList<>();
}



package com.example.springpractice.Models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tags {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String tag_name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product products;
}
```

Here is the Repos:

```
package com.example.springpractice.Repositories;

import com.example.springpractice.Models.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {

    Product findByProductName(String productName);

    Product findByCategoryId(int categoryId);
}


package com.example.springpractice.Repositories;

import com.example.springpractice.Models.Tags;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface TagInterface extends JpaRepository<Tags, Integer> {
    
}
```

here is the service:

```
@Service
public class ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Autowired
    private TagInterface tagInterface;

    public Product saveProduct(Product product, List<Tags> tags)
    {
        for(Tags tag : tags){
            tag.setProducts(product);
            tagInterface.save(tag);
        }
        product.setTags(tags);
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }
}
```

its not saving and giving me errors.

```
"No primary or single unique constructor found for interface"
```

Comment: Where did the error happen exactly? In the service class ProductService? Or maybe in the RestController calling it?

Comment: @Mar-Z in the product Service